# I am trying to install ELK and there are different version of elastic , kibana and logstash

Tags: elastic-stack

I am trying to install ELK stack for testing, But the version are different of Elastic , Kibana and logstash.
Does this different version will make difference and how can i install all the latest version on Linux.

I want ELK stack to be on version 6  (all tool version 6 )

OS - Cent OS 6
JDK-1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not problems to have nodes ELK stack in different versions if they do not diverge *to much*...

So if you have 5.6.x elasticserch cluster 5.3.x Logstash and 5.2.x Kibana. Still everything should work fine together. For your testign it will be probably sufficient.

If your ELK is on 6.x everything should work fine together even if some part are ~ 5.5.x

However it's better to check Breaking changes for production:
Version by version tool by tool:
 - [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes.html)
 - [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.1/breaking-changes.html)
 - [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/breaking-changes.html)

If i got you correct, you have some diff in versions, that are available as official packages on you Cent OS 6 distribution? Please provide more details on versions you have and you expect to see...

Comment: [link(]https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-logs-on-centos-6)

I am trying to install from this link,

Comment: @RaghuReddy i would not use this link, pretty old stuff is referenced there: Use offcial docu instead https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_installation.html